# How to rewrite serviceId for Spring Cloud Gateway with service discovery

Tags: java, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm migrating zuul gateway to SCG. My services are running in kubernetes & registered via consul.
Typical service name is xxx-service. So with current gateway config I can call them by http://address/api/xxx-service/some-path

My current config:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
          predicates:
            - name: Path
              args:
                pattern: "'/api/' + serviceId + '/**'"
          filters:
            - name: RewritePath
              args:
                regexp: "'/api/' + serviceId + '/(?<remaining>.*)'"
                replacement: "'/${remaining}'"
```

But clients should call them without '-service' suffix in service name. How to configure SCG to be able to call services by
http://address/api/xxx-service/some-path

Previos zuul configuration:

```
zuul.routes.xxx.service-id=xxx-service
zuul.routes.aaa-bbb.service-id=aaa-bbb-service
zuul.routes.aaa-bbb.path=/aaa/bbb/**
zuul.strip-prefix=true
zuul.prefix=/api
```

Comment: do you konw how to config right now? @Silk0vsky

Comment: Hi @Dolphin, sorry for late response. I've recreated my solution as an answer. Please share yours if you have one.

Answer (score 2):

I am in the exactly same position. Did you find the trick to solve this ?
I know we can define all route in the RouteLocator like this :

```
/**
 * Route constructions.
 *
 * @param builder
 *                the builder instance
 * @return the final route locator
 */
@Bean
public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(final RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
return builder.routes()
    // Declare First service
    .route(r -> r.path("/prefix/myservice1-service/**")
        .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("/prefix/myservicename1-service/(?<remaining>.*)", "/${remaining}"))
        .uri("lb://myservice1").id("myservice1"))

    // Declare Second service
    .route(r -> r.path("/prefix/myservice2-service/**")
        .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("/prefix/myservicename2-service/(?<remaining>.*)", "/${remaining}"))
        .uri("lb://myservice2").id("myservice2"))

    // Etc... Then build
    .build();
}
```

I am not sure but maybe you need to disable the discovery locator in order to do that properly.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: false
```

but it could be great to get a less dirty solution.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Rémi Gélibert variant, we can implement our own **RouteLocator**. It allows you to specify predicate for your routes selection and special filter that able to **mutate request as you wish**.

This way we can extract our routing configuration to some kind of `application.properties`.

```
@Component
public class CustomRouteLocator implements RouteLocator {

  Map<String, Pattern> prefixPatternsByServiceNames; // external configuration
  Map<String, String> prefixesByServiceNames;        // external configuration 
  Set<String> servicesNames;                         // external configuration

  @Override
  public Flux<Route> getRoutes() {

    return Flux.fromIterable(servicesNames)
        .map(serviceName -> Route.async()
            .id("ROUTE_" + serviceName)
            .predicate(exchange -> {
              String path = exchange.getRequest().getPath().toString();
              return prefixPatternsByServiceNames.get(serviceName).matcher(path).find();
            })
            .filter((exchange, chain) -> {
              ServerHttpRequest origRequest = exchange.getRequest();
              String query = origRequest.getURI().getQuery();
              String originalPath = origRequest.getPath().toString();
              String newPath = originalPath.substring(prefixesByServiceNames.get(serviceName).length());

              ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest().mutate()
                  .path(query == null? newPath : newPath + "?" + query)
                  .build();
              return chain.filter(exchange.mutate()
                  .request(request)
                  .build());
            })
            .uri("http://" + serviceName)
            .build());
  }

}
```

Please note:

My gateway relies on kubernetes service discovery, so I'm rewriting `uri` this way `uri("http://" + serviceName)`

In case you have consul/eurica discovery integrtion, you could try to do it other way: `uri("lb://" + serviceName)`

Answer (score 1):

You can make the following configurations to achieve your needs:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
          # defaults is in GatewayDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class
          # SpEL expression context is ServiceInstance.class
          predicates:
            - name: Path
              args:
                pattern: "'/api/'+serviceId.replace('-service', '')+'/**'"
          filters:
            - name: RewritePath
              args:
                regexp: "'/api/.+/?(?<remaining>.*)'"
                replacement: "'/api/'+serviceId+'/${remaining}'"
```

Official docs: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#configuring-predicates-and-filters-for-discoveryclient-routes